# How to add a column in R of the item's length in another column

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(y=sample( c("A","B","C"), 10, T), 
                X=sample(c (1,2,3), 10, T))
   y X
1  A 3
2  C 2
3  B 3
4  C 2
5  C 1
6  A 3
7  B 1
8  C 1
9  B 1
10 B 3
```

what I wanted is to add a column `z` which summarize the items' length of column `y` such as:

```
   y X z
1  A 3 2
2  C 2 4
3  B 3 4
4  C 2 4
5  C 1 4
6  A 3 2
7  B 1 4
8  C 1 4
9  B 1 4
10 B 3 4
```

which means there are 2 As, 4 Cs and 4 Bs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to create the column 'z' based on the number of elements (.N) for each 'y'.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, z:= .N, by = y]
DT
#    y X z
# 1: A 3 2
# 2: C 2 4
# 3: B 3 4
# 4: C 2 4
# 5: C 1 4
# 6: A 3 2
# 7: B 1 4
# 8: C 1 4
# 9: B 1 4
#10: B 3 4
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'y' and create a new column 'z' with `mutate`.  The `dplyr` equivalent to `.N` is `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(y) %>%
   mutate(z = n())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$z=table(df$y)[df$y]
df
#    y X z
# 1  A 3 2
# 2  C 2 4
# 3  B 3 4
# 4  C 2 4
# 5  C 1 4
# 6  A 3 2
# 7  B 1 4
# 8  C 1 4
# 9  B 1 4
# 10 B 3 4
```

With `table` we are able to get both the counts and the names of each element of the `df$y` column. So that saves steps along the way. We are leveraging the strength of being able to both subset by indices **and** names. In this case, the column is of the class `factor`, but the above will also work if they were `as.character`.

Comment: I'm not sure regarding the names. Try `as.vector(table(df$y))[df$y]`, for example. `as.vector` strips the names. In this case it seem to work due to the fact that `df$y` is an integer (factor) in this example. Though when `y` is of class `character` it seem to work according to names. Quite tricky.

Comment: Yes @DavidArenburg , the factor is working underneath. But something cool is that even if the strings were characters the name subset would work but not the value. `table(df$y)[as.character(df$y)]` will still work due to name subsetting. But `as.vector(table(df$y))[as.character(df$y)]` won't.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote it in my comment above :). Worth investigation :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just saw the edit. Flexible subsetting is the type of R feature that keeps people interested and puts R above other platforms. That along with matrix operations really show the power of the language :)

Comment: Though it may introduce some inconsistency...

Comment: @DavidArenburg how so?

Comment: Because some types it operates over names of the table and sometimes over its values. I'm not sure its very consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using a `for` loop:

```
for (i in levels(df$y)) df$z[df$y==i] <- sum(df$y==i)  
#> df
#   y X z
#1  A 3 2
#2  C 2 4
#3  B 3 4
#4  C 2 4
#5  C 1 4
#6  A 3 2
#7  B 1 4
#8  C 1 4
#9  B 1 4
#10 B 3 4
```

Comment: With base I would just go with `with(df, ave(X, y, FUN = length))`

Comment: Or maybe `with(df, ave(as.numeric(y), y, FUN = length))` for more consistency or `with(df, ave(seq(y), y, FUN = length))`